# Generalize a method to work with various objects

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, reflection, casting

In a program I'm writing, I've decided to use my own data types instead of any other database ( for educational purposes).

The data is saved as csv files, and i have a method to convert from .csv to a simple string[,].

Each class X as it's own string[,] to List converter.
After the first 3 classes i started to play with generics and reflection.
I did succeed converting a general List to string[,], but doing the opposite is started to look hard.

the way i implement List to string[,] is:

```
public string[,] ToArray(object[] sender)
    {
        if (sender.Length==0)
        {

            return null;
        }
        string[,] ret; 
        PropertyInfo[] props;
        if (sender.Length > 0)
        {
            props = sender[0].GetType().GetProperties();
            ret = new string[props.Length, sender.Length];
        }
        else
        {

            return null;
        }
        for (int i=0;i<sender.Length;i++)
        {



            for (int p = 0; p < props.Length; p++)
            {
                object value=props[p].GetValue(sender[i], null);
               if (value!=null) ret[p, i] = value.ToString();

            }


        }
        return ret;


    }
```

and for lets say class Windows( string Name, double Size, bool Blinds)

i convert array[,] to Windows ( very generally ) like this :

```
public static List<Windows> ToList(string[,] arra)
    {

        List<Windows> ret = new List<Windows>(); // change Windows to anything
        int col = array.GetLength(1);
        int row = array.GetLength(0);

        PropertyInfo[] props=PropArray(new Windows());
        int propslen=props.Length;
        for (int c = 0; c < col; c++)
        {
            Windows entry=new Windows();
            for (int r = 0; r < propslen; r++)
            {
                Type pt = props[r].PropertyType;

                if (pt==typeof(string))
                    props[r].SetValue(entry,array[r,c],null);
                else
                    if (pt==typeof(int))
                    {
                        int i=0;int.TryParse(array[r,c],out i);
                    props[r].SetValue(entry,i,null);
                    }
                else
                    if (pt==typeof(bool))
                    {
                        bool i = false; bool.TryParse(array[r, c], out i);
                    props[r].SetValue(entry,i,null);
                    }
                    else
                        if (pt == typeof(double))
                        {
                            double i = 0; double.TryParse(array[r, c], out i);
                            props[r].SetValue(entry, i, null);
                        }
                    else
                if (pt==typeof(DateTime))
                    {
                        DateTime i = DateTime.MinValue; DateTime.TryParse(array[r, c], out i);
                    props[r].SetValue(entry,i,null);
                    }





            }
            ret.Add(entry);


            }

        return ret;


        }
```

All i need to do is FindReplace the word "Windows" to any other datatype and it works.

The real question is how can i generalize it to receive a type and make a list of instances  it all by itself?

Is it even possible?

Thanks in advance,
Gabriel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will not be foolproof, but you can use generics. Something like:

```
public static List<T> ToList<T>(string[,] arra) // T can be anything
    where T : new()                             // as long as it has a default constructor
{

    List<T> ret = new List<T>();
    int col = array.GetLength(1);
    int row = array.GetLength(0);

    PropertyInfo[] props=PropArray(new T());
    int propslen=props.Length;
    for (int c = 0; c < col; c++)
    {
        T entry=new T();
// ...
```

Comment: Thanks guys, Anders for a new perspective ( too late to change now, but there's always new projects :] ). And madd0 for the answer i was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is essentially a serialization format. Serialization formats are relatively simple if objects are values without complex references. Simple xml or json are common formats. Perhaps you should look into using json?

If you go for "roll your own", why not try to use property names as keys? Prefix the key/value list with the class name and instantiate the objects when you deserialize. Example format

```
MyApplication.Person, MyAssembly
Name=Steve
Age=30
MyApplication.Person, MyAssembly
Name=Bob
Age=54
```

To deserialize, read the class name, instatiate using FormatterServices.GetUninitializedObject() to get an empty instance of the class. Then using the property infos of that class, set the values from the key/value pairs that follow in the file. This is essentially a simplified JSON notation (does not support lists,maps etc.)